How to Parameterize a query in Azure Data Factory copy activity
I have the following query in our ADF Copy Activity
SELECT
  deltaTable.*
FROM Data.deltaTable
LEFT OUTER JOIN Data.targetTable
  ON deltaTable.signature = targetTable.signature
WHERE targetTable.signature IS NULL

Can someone let me know how to parameterize the query. When I attempt to parameterize the query I get the error:
Parameter schema was not found under EX_SourceToRaw_Single_Table

The following code is my attempt:
@concat('SELECT * FROM ',pipeline().parameters.schema,'.',pipeline().parameters.DeltaTable)
LEFT OUTER JOIN pipeline().parameters.schema,'.',pipeline().parameters.TargetTable)
  ON pipeline().parameters.DeltaTable).signature = pipeline().parameters.TargetTable).signature
WHERE pipeline().parameters.TargetTable).signature IS NULL

The deltaTable and the TargetTable both look like the following:
==========================================================================================================
|    CountryName     |    CountryISO2     |    CountryISO3     |    SalesRegion     |     signature      |
==========================================================================================================
|      Belgium       |     CHA            |     10             |        EMEA        |800e559a27d68f0478b6|
|                    |                    |                    |                    |1c4c9f009e2418e86697|
|                    |                    |                    |                    |1b6e54b549b51b1367ab|
|                    |                    |                    |                    |        450d        |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       Wales        |     steveO         |     WAL            |       Welsh        |e8c5149d54986dfe9ac9|
|                    |                    |                    |                    |5a60a76b07603fe17c28|
|                    |                    |                    |                    |2b552ec8255f123b279a|
|                    |                    |                    |                    |        533a        |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      Germany       |     DE             |     deletedupd     |        EMEA        |1232b1bd91d14a87ed83|
|                    |                    |                    |                    |0f770d74cd8cabb87153|
|                    |                    |                    |                    |5c4c2b7ff5bcb873fa80|
|                    |                    |                    |                    |        d851        |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       Italy        |     IT             |     ITA            |        EMEA        |584cf66de2f4af9eb4db|
|                    |                    |                    |                    |febefea808b1b4e6a357|
|                    |                    |                    |                    |87fcac1061de88cfb798|
|                    |                    |                    |                    |        56df        |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Can you provide the values of parameters? and is that the same expression that you are using in the activity? or any typo missing? and what is the source here for that query?

Hi @RakeshGovindula, I have updated the question to describe tables. The schema is dbo. I hope that is what you were asking for

Can you once go to the pipeline run -> copy activity run input (click on arrow ->) and it will show the exact query which you are generating from expression. Can you provide that?. If possible provide an image of the pipeline expression that you were using.

I am getting syntax errors upon trying your pipeline expressions. If you want, I can provide the exact pipeline expression with parameters which can generate the query that you have provided? Can I?

Hi @RakeshGovindula, sorry for the delayed response. It's not possible to run the pipeline with the code I attempted.

Hi @RakeshGovindula, yes can you please provide the exact pipeline expresssion with parameter which can generate the query

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

After creating the schema, DeltaTable,TargetTable parameters in ADF pipeline, use the below expression in the query option of the copy activity. Here, for sample I have used lookup activity query option which will work same as copy activity query option.
@concat('SELECT ',pipeline().parameters.DeltaTable,'.* FROM ',pipeline().parameters.schema,'.',pipeline().parameters.DeltaTable,' LEFT OUTER JOIN ',pipeline().parameters.schema,'.',pipeline().parameters.TargetTable,' ON ',pipeline().parameters.DeltaTable,'.signature = ',pipeline().parameters.TargetTable,'.signature WHERE ',pipeline().parameters.TargetTable,'.signature IS NULL')

Open the dynamic content in the query and give the above expression as shown below.

To check generated query, you can go to the pipeline run -> activity run -> Input. Here, it will show the query that was generated from the above expression. You can see it generated the required query.

If you get any error, you can cross the check the generated query here and can modify it as per your requirement.

Hi @Rakesh, thank you very much. This was a complete success
